# failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error, need help on rectifying this error

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

while running the main.py i'm geeting error

```
2022-05-12 18:56:09.133235: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
2022-05-12 18:56:09.205977: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: Vijaya-PC
2022-05-12 18:56:09.206495: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: Vijaya-PC
2022-05-12 18:56:09.326105: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vijaya\Desktop\it-project\main.py", line 41, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('Emotion Detector',frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1268: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

Comment: Please format the error message properly (don't remove newlines before pasting) so that it is easily readable. Also, can you paste your main.py using github gist or any other way?

Comment: this is multiple errors. (1) tensorflow can't use cuda so it'll probably fallback to CPU. (2) your OpenCV package is the `headless` variant, so you can't use `imshow`. remove the package and install a non-headless variant instead.